# Unicode Characters Not Displaying after scp to Server

Tags: debian, ubuntu, vim, webserver, character-encoding

I want to upload some html files to my webserver (running Debian 10 buster) from my laptop (running Ubuntu 20.04). I did so by using `scp` to transfer the files as a tarball to the remote server.

For some reason, quotation marks (and other UTF-8 chars) in my document get scrambled to something like `â€œ`.

This problem is visible when looking at the files on the server (using vim) and on the website itself, which is served using nginx.
Using `file -bi` I have made sure that the encoding of the files on my Ubuntu PC and the Debian Server are both nominally UTF-8.
Furthermore, I have checked that `nginx.conf` has the `charset utf-8;` set correctly, which it seems to have.

How can I make sure that the file encoding is preserved/displayed correctly on the server?

Comment: just to be sure, when viewing file in browser after seting your encoding to UTF-8, do file display properly  ? It might be a problem on nginx not sending enconding information.

Comment: Check the output of the `locale` command on the two machines - they would need to be identical. For example both "en_GB.UTF-8". Unicode is a character set, but UTF-8 is an encoding. ;)

Comment: @Archemar I did check, I also included a `<meta charset ...>` flag

Comment: @JeremyBoden I just checked the output from `locale`, seems to be the same actually...